# How to use the real input connector in OpenModelica?

Tags: python, simulation, modelica, openmodelica

I would like to have a OpenModelica model like the following:
[image: Model from OMEdit]

On the left side there is a "Real Input Connector" called *u* and on the right side there is a "Real Output Connector" called *y*. 
The Porpose of the model is just to take a value (*u*) multiply it with 2 and give back the output (*y*).

Now my questions: 
How do I set a value to the input variabe *u*?

Is the input connector the right block to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is valid if you want this gain to be a standalone submodule that you'll connect to other models.  In that case you need to connect the output of a source to your input block.  The standard library provides a variety in Modelica.Blocks.Sources, or you can make your own.

As a trivial example, with your example saved as My_Gain.mo, to connect to sinusoidal source:

```
model SampleModel
  My_Gain gain;
  Modelica.Blocks.Sources.Sine source;

equation
  connect(source.y, gain.u);
end SampleModel;
```

Without knowing more about what you're trying to do, it's hard to say if this is the right way to go about it, but it will work.

Comment: You answered the first part of my question. Thanks for that. In order to accept your answer I changed my question and made a second one which is here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20966511/how-can-i-call-an-openmodelica-model-in-python-with-ompython